# Groovy representation of Notification plugin in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

How to represent the Notifications Endpoint section of the Jenkins job configuration in a Jenkinsfile (in the form of a groovy script) ? I have installed the Notification plugin but I am not sure how I would use that.

Comment: https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/sending-notifications-pipeline... or just look into Pipeline syntax the option should be there

Comment: Hi Rohit, 
I was actually referring to the section where you need to add an endpoint where the parameters are as follows:

Format: JSON . 

Protocol: HTTP . 

Event: Job Finalized

URL: {my_url} 

Timeout: 9000

Log: -1

Answer (score 0):

In my jenkins pipeline I did the following:

```
pipeline {
// ..
stages {
    stage('Notify') {

    script { 
        def build = currentBuild // global variable in pipeline -> https://opensource.triology.de/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals#currentBuild

        def targetUrl = "http://some-url?{some-query-params}"
        def buildUrl = build.absoluteUrl
        def buildNumber = build.number
        def buildStatus = build.currentResult

        httpRequest url: targetUrl, contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', httpMode: 'POST', responseHandle: 'NONE', timeout: 30, requestBody: """
        {
            "name": "${args.serviceName}",
            "build": {
                "full_url": "${buildUrl}",
                "number": "${buildNumber}",
                "phase": "FINISHED",
                "status": "${buildStatus}"
            }
        }
        """
    }
}
```